# How to attach a text file stored locally in app directory

Tags: android

I have an Android app that saves a text file directly onto the phone, in the app's install directory. I need to allow the user to create a new email, attaching this saved text file. When I start the intent to send the email, everything shows up in Gmail correctly, but the attachment does not get sent. All of my searches on stack overflow seem to only deal with attaching an image file from the SD card. Below is the code that I used. Please let me know if I have done something incorrectly.

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + "someFile.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = null;

if( file != null )
{
    steam = openFileOutput("someFile.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    stream.write(some_data);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email_text);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    file.close();

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
}
```

I've also tried sendIntent.setType("application/octet-stream"); but that didn't make a difference. I'm at a loss for why the file doesn't attach and get sent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before and the only way I could solve it was by writing the file to the SD card.

It's worth trying writing to the file to the SD card and attaching it if only to eliminate the files location as the cause of the problem.

Comment: hmmm... that's unfortunate. I'll give this a try and see if that works better. Thanks Al.

What approach did you take if no SD card was present? Did you decide to just attach all of your file data in the EXTRA_TEXT portion of the Intent email?

Comment: If no card was present I show a "You need an SD card message".

I know it's far from ideal, but it avoids the issue of users complaining that the attachment didn't arrive as an attachment and issues relating to them doing File -> Save in their mail client and complaining their other application couldn't import the file (due to mail headers being in the file).

Comment: Thanks again Al. Changing my code to store the file on the SD card works.

Answer (score 5):

I've just run into exactly the same issue (wanting to attach a text file to a Gmail message). If you look in the Android log, the reason for it is:

```
02-28 21:01:28.434: E/Gmail(19673): file:// attachment paths must point to file:///mnt/sdcard. Ignoring attachment file:///data/data/com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach/cache/Test.txt
```

As a workaround, you can use a ContentProvider to provide access to files in your application's internal cache so that Gmail can attach them. I've just written up a [blog post](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974) on how to do it.

Hopefully that's of some help :)

Comment: Thanks stephendnicholas, I will check out your post!

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer I found actually deal with the problem ("Attachment NOT in SD") eventhought I haven't try your approach yet (and don't know if it works). I've bookmarked your blog post.