# Send with attachment from internal app folder

Tags: android, email, android-intent, send

I have created file in my internal app folder via Context method "openFileOutput" with MODE_WORLD_READABLE mode.

Now I would like to attach this file with a ACTION_SEND intent eg. to email. 
I see the file in attachments during sending, but message comes without any attachment.

Is there a problem with attaching file from app folder even if it is in MODE_WORLD_READABLE?
Is there any workaround?

Best,
Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no quick&easy way to do this. There're some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490739/617232

Most people change their approach to use SD Card though.