# Let your app attach files to email etc

Tags: java, android

My application lets the user save files, but now i want to give the user the possibility to get out of my app and share the files. So i created an intend. If you do this, Android lets you select the way of exporting the file. If you choose e-mail, a new mail with attachment and attachment size will appear. But if i send the mail, i won't receive any attachments.

I'm afraid this happens because the mail app is not able to access the files in my app's folder. If this is the reason, is there an other way? I didn't find any information about this.

This is the code:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+longClickItem);
if (file.exists() == true) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getListView().getCheckedItemIds());
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Copy file to some temp directory & then pass uri of this file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach a text file stored locally in app directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209304/how-to-attach-a-text-file-stored-locally-in-app-directory)

Comment: Thank you. But how do i find out the best temp folder which is accessable from other apps?